# Customize Partner Portal Home Page Layout

Tags: home-page-component, partner-portal

Hi I have got Partner Portal for my Org. and I would like to customize its Home Page with the elements that I had written in my Visualforce page. Because, we can't have Dashboards in Partner Portal, I had written a Visaulforce page and now I would like to have it displayed in the Home Page of the Partner Portal.

Regards

Answer (score 2):

SF really only allows you to easily [edit the header, footer, logo and log-in message](https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=partner_portal_details.htm&language=en_US) on Partner Portal. The rest is like a detail page. I don't believe the log-in controller for a Partner Portal will allow you to point to a custom VF page, but I suggest you check your controller to make certain. My Dev Org here doesn't have a Partner Portal for me to check; instead only a Community.

As you're already aware,  you can't have [Dashboards in a Partner Portal](https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=users_license_types_partnerportal.htm) so I'm doubtful that substituting a custom VF page will provide that functionality for you. However, you can have them in a [Partner Community](https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=users_license_types_communities.htm). My suggestion would be to convert your Portal to a Community. Your current Partner Portal license will also work for a community, giving you essentially the same functionality with the added features. Before you begin building a community, I recommend you thoroughly compare the object access for read/write on the objects your current partner portal is using as there may be some slight differences between a Community and a Portal that either aren't apparent in the charts or that I've overlooked. That said, I'd generally expect your partners to get more from a community than from your existing portal.